# Verificação de campo de password com JS

Tags: javascript

Fiz um filtro para verificar se o campo de senha continha no mínimo 6 caracteres, porém, agora preciso retornar uma mensagem de erro caso não possua.

Já tentei utilizar map, pois a aplicação já continha um erro genérico, mas preciso de um para esse tipo específico de erro

Meu campo de senha é este:

```
.mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label
            input#newPassword.mdl-textfield__input(type="password" data-validation="password-register" name="newPassword")
            label.mdl-textfield__label(for="newPassword")= __('reset-password.form.new-password')
            span.mdl-textfield__error
```

```
  event.preventDefault();
  const invalidFields = getInvalidFields(event.target, {
    validations: {
      'password-register': {
        passwordPolicy: element => element.value.length >= 6,
        message: 'A senha deve ter ao menos 6 caracteres.',
      },
    },
  });

  if (invalidFields.length) {
    showErrorMessage(invalidFields);
    return;
  }
```

```
  Array.from(form.elements)
    .filter(element => element instanceof HTMLInputElement)
    .filter(input => (
      !input.value
      || (validations[input.dataset.validation]
        && !validations[input.dataset.validation].passwordPolicy(input))
    ))
);

export const showErrorMessage = invalidFields => (
  invalidFields.forEach((input) => {
    input.parentElement.lastElementChild.innerHTML = 'Campo obrigatório';
    input.passwordPolicy.innerHTML = 'Errrooooooooow'; //não funciona
    input.parentElement.classList.add('is-invalid');
  })
);
```

Comment: Podes mostrar essa função `getInvalidFields`?

Comment: OLá Sergio! Esta função está sendo criada no 2 bloco de codigos, logo nas primeiras linhas

Comment: Flávia, não vejo onde essa função está, aqui na pergunta... podes adicionar?